# WinInet and InternetOpen

Tags: c++, wininet

The documentation states that InternetOpen can be called multiple times without any issues. My question though is should I be calling InternetCloseHandle on handle returned by it multiple times?

For example, I have a class I call `CAPIRequestContext`, which has a handle which is returned by InternetOpen. Each one of my requests has it's own copy. Right now, I call InternetCloseHandle in the destructor, so it gets called multiple times.

I'm wondering if the following could cause issues:
Thread A creates a `CAPIRequestObject` which calls InternetOpen and stores the handle. Thread B does the same, but then goes out of scope before Thread A exits, so Thread B calls the destructor in it's own `CAPIRequestObject`, which calls `InternetCloseHandle` on the handle returned by InternetOpen.

Should I remove the call to InternetCloseHandle in the destructors of my class? At least for the InternetHandle? I assume I should call InternetCloseHandle for the handle returned by HttpOpenRequest.

I have similar questions regarding the handle returned by InternetConnect. Are these handles shared?

Here is some sample code, minus some external code that I don't think is related to the issue:

```
class CAPIClient;
class CAPIRequest
{
public:
     CAPIRequestContext()
     {
         m_hConn = NULL;
         m_hInternet = NULL;
         m_hRequest = NULL;
     }

     ~CAPIRequestContext()
     {
         if (m_hRequest) InternetCloseHandle(m_hRequest);
         if (m_hConn) InternetCloseHandle(m_hConn);
         if (m_hInternet) InternetCloseHandle(m_hInternet);
     }

     bool Init(const CAPIClient &client, const std::string &uri, const std::string &method)
     {
          ATLASSERT(!(m_hInternet || m_hConn || m_hRequest));
          if (m_hInternet || m_hConn || m_hRequest) throw std::exception("Cannot init request more than once.");

          bool success = false;
          m_AuthToken = *client.m_pAuthToken;
          URI = uri;
          m_hInternet = InternetOpen("MyApp", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
DWORD requestTimeout = 60 * 1000; // Set timeout to 60 seconds instead of 30

          if (m_hInternet)
          {  
                InternetSetOption(m_hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, &requestTimeout, sizeof(requestTimeout));
                m_hConn = InternetConnect(m_hInternet, (LPSTR)client.m_host.c_str(), client.m_port, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, (DWORD_PTR)this);
                if (m_hConn) {
                      m_hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(m_hConn, method.c_str(), uri.c_str(), "HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL, client.GetOpenRequestFlags(), 0);
                }
                if (m_hRequest)
                {
                    success = true;
                }
          }
       return success;
     }      
}

    // There are additional calls like 
    // SendRequest
    // GetData
    // GetFullResponse

private:
     // Added these methods to make sure I'm not copying the handles
enter code here
     CAPIRequestContext(const CAPIRequestContext &other) = delete;
     CAPIRequestContext& operator=(const CAPIRequestContext& other) = delete;

private:
      HINTERNET m_hInternet;
      HINTERNET m_hConn;
      HINTERNET m_hRequest;

}
```

Comment: Every InternetOpen() must be exactly paired with an InternetCloseHandle() that passes the handle you got from the open call.  Little reason to assume that your code is not already doing that.  Feel good about it by using assert() on the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The documentation states that InternetOpen can be called multiple times without any issues. My question though is should I be calling InternetCloseHandle on handle returned by it multiple times?

Yes, as is stated in [`InternetOpen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096.aspx) documentation:

> After the calling application has finished using the [`HINTERNET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383766.aspx) handle returned by `InternetOpen`, **it must be closed using the [`InternetCloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384350.aspx) function**.

> For example, I have a class I call `CAPIRequestContext`, which has a handle which is returned by `InternetOpen`. Each one of my requests has it's own copy. Right now, I call `InternetCloseHandle` in the destructor, so it gets called multiple times.

That would be a correct implementation, if each instance of the class calls `InternetOpen()`, or otherwise obtains ownership of a unique `HINTERNET`.

**HOWEVER**, do be aware that such a class needs to implement the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  Basically, if you have to provide a destructor to release a resource, you also need to provide a copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator as well.

But, you can't call `InternetCloseHandle()` multiple times on the same `HINTERNET`, so you can't have multiple `CAPIRequestContext` using the same `HINTERNET` and all of them calling `InternetCloseHandle()`<sup>1</sup>.  So, your copy constructor and copy-assignment operator must either:

1. take ownership of the `HINTERNET` from the source `CAPIRequestContext` that is being copied.
2. be disabled completely to prevent copying one `CAPIRequestContext` to another.

In your case, I would opt for #2.

<sup>1</sup>: You would need a per-instance flag indicating which instance can call it and which ones cannot. But this is not good class design.  If you need to share an `HINTERNET`, you should implement reference counting semantics instead, such as provided by `std::shared_ptr`.

> I'm wondering if the following could cause issues: Thread A creates a CAPIRequestObject which calls InternetOpen and stores the handle. Thread B does the same, but then goes out of scope before Thread A exits, so Thread B calls the destructor in it's own CAPIRequestObject, which calls InternetCloseHandle on the handle returned by InternetOpen.

That is perfectly safe, provided each `CAPIRequestObject` has its own `HINTERNET`.

> Should I remove the call to InternetCloseHandle in the destructors of my class?

No, if each class instance holds a unique `HINTERNET`.

> I assume I should call InternetCloseHandle for the handle returned by HttpOpenRequest.

Yes, as is stated in the [`HttpOpenRequest()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233.aspx) documentation:

> After the calling application has finished using the [`HINTERNET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383766.aspx) handle returned by `HttpOpenRequest`, **it must be closed using the [`InternetCloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384350.aspx) function**.

> I have similar questions regarding the handle returned by InternetConnect. Are these handles shared?

Each `HINTERNET` must be closed individually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'm doing all of that, though I have to check the copy constructor and copy assignment is overridden to make sure that I'm not making copies.

Comment: I'm trying to track down a big that appears to possibly be caused by one instance of my CAPITequestContext getting destroyed and causing issues on other threads using WinInet in the same app. Basically changing the order of some calls in the call seems to fix the issue and I think it may be related to destructors being called.

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no one here can help you with that.

Comment: Also, in the docs it says "After the calling application has finished using the HINTERNET handle returned by InternetOpen, it must be closed using the InternetCloseHandle function.", and it occured to me that "the calling application" might mean that even though you might call InternetOpen multiple times that the application might only be allowed to call InternetCloseHandle on that handle once.

Comment: As for the example, I'd post one, but what I'm getting is an intermittent crash which I can only reproduce in Release mode, so right now I'm just speculating.

Comment: @bpeikes if you stop speculating and show what you have so far, someone can tell you if you are on the right track or not. Every call to `InternetOpen()` is a new `HINTERNET`, it must be released with its own call to `InternetCloseHandle()`, regardless of any other `HINTERNET` that exists. `InternetCloseHandle()` can only be called once on each `HINTERNET`.

Comment: I asked the question for clarification that I'm doing things correctly, and it appears that I am. Each request has it's own internet, connection and request handles, which they clean up in their destructors.

The issue I'm having has to do with possible interaction between two requests. It seems to be a timing issue in that it does not happen all the time. The code for creating and destroying requests is straight forward, and was following all of the rules you outlined above.

Comment: If your requests are kept separate properly then there is no opportunity for conflict. So you must not be managing your requests correctly.  But no one can see what you are actually doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114079/discussion-between-bpeikes-and-remy-lebeau).